# Need to display date and time above Login in Magento page

Tags: magento, date

I need to display date and time above Login in Magento page. I changed the Menus of My Account, Login with Contact Us & About Us, and now I need to display date and time above these options in header.phtml.
 I used the below code:
`'<div class="date-time">
<?php echo strftime('%c');?>
</div>'`
Time and date is showing on site, but not exactly where I want. Any support will be highly apreciated.
Site: www.ozams.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move your code above ul tag like:

```
<div class="header-right">
        ............... 
        <div class="clear"></div>         
        <div style="text-align: right;" class="date-time">
               <?php echo strftime('%c');?>
          </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="links">
              <li class="first"><a title="Contact Us" href="contact-us">Contact us</a></li>
              <li class=" last"><a title="About Us" href="http://ozams.com/index.php/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
```